# converting massive extended insert to simple insert for mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, scripting, text, query-optimization

Long story from my weekend with an EC2 instance. Dumped the data I massaged there into a 685MB dump file to move over to my server. Early morning so didn't detect that I had the option set for an extended insert. I don't have access to the massaged data in the temporary database as I figured I was covered with the dump file.

So now I have this dumpfile that includes a table that has one extended insert with 17 million rows. The mysql on my server choked on it.

I did find a perl script called [mysqdump-convert.pl](http://platon.sk/cvs/cvs.php/scripts/perl/mysql/mysqldump-convert.pl) that converts the extended inserts into simple ones. I piped its output into a new file, but it appears to have choked after 144MB of the 685MB task.

Is there any other tool you know of that can handle this task? Thanks.

Comment: Are you importing the dump from the command line? Importing 17 million rows should be ok using an extended insert.

Comment: @maclema I tried importing from the command line yesterday afternoon. It imported two large tables (million or so rows with way more data) but stopped after about two million lines of the 17M row table which is only three numeric fields. Is there a timeout in mysql I should be looking for?

Comment: @maclema found the csplit utility. Will see if splitting the file by the start of each table will make it more manageable.

Comment: sigh...even using csplit it still stopped after 3.4 million rows. Maybe I'll try running the mysqdump-convert script on the csplit result.

Comment: @lan I found so in this type o stuff - just build you own utility in php/python etc... its a time saver...

Comment: You could try using sed to convert the file to TSV format and then use LOAD DATA INFILE.  This would let you load much smaller chunks and see where the hangup is. You say that is 'chokes' and 'stops', but what actually happens?

Comment: have you tried [link](http://rodo.nl/index.php?page=mysql-splitter) mysl-splitter? I never tried it, so can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 2):

Making a bullet-proof script to do this would be a pain. However, to do it for just your data is probably easy.

If you are starting with this:

```
INSERT INTO tblTable VALUES (1,4,"String"),(2,4,"String"),(3,4,"String");
```

You can do a search and replace, using your favorite editor:

```
Find:   ,(
Replace with: ;\nINSERT INTO tblTable VALUES (
```

Now, glance through and make sure it looks correct and let it rip.